# How to fix android studio. The database is not update

Tags: java, android

I try to update the database in android studio with this. But I don't know how to do, I use every thing to do but it's impossible. Can everybody help me.

This is PersonalFrag.java:

```
public class PersonalFrag extends Fragment {
    private EditText editName, editEmail, editUsername, editPassword;
    private Button editButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false);

        // Initialize EditText fields
        editName = view.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        editEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        editUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        editPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        editButton = view.findViewById(R.id.editButton);

        // Retrieve data from arguments
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String name = bundle.getString("name", "");
            String email = bundle.getString("email", "");
            String username = bundle.getString("username", "");
            String password = bundle.getString("password", "");

            // Populate EditText fields
            editName.setText(name);
            editEmail.setText(email);
            editUsername.setText(username);
            editPassword.setText(password);
            // Note: You might not want to display the password in the UI
            // editPassword.setText(password);
        }


        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Navigate to EditProfile activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditProfile.class);


                intent.putExtra("name", editName.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("email", editEmail.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("username", editUsername.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("password", editPassword.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is EditProfile.java:

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editName, editEmail, editUsername, editPassword;
    Button saveButton;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    HelperClass helperClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        editName = findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editEmail = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        editUsername = findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userProfiles");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            editName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));
            editEmail.setText(intent.getStringExtra("email"));
            editUsername.setText(intent.getStringExtra("username"));
            editPassword.setText(intent.getStringExtra("password"));
        }

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showConfirmationDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showConfirmationDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Save Changes?");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to save the changes?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Save changes
                saveChanges();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Cancelled
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void saveChanges() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your saveChanges method is empty, what part of updating the db are you encountering?